# Failed to enable unit: Access denied - while enabling a service on AWS RHEL instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redhat, service

When I run this command

```
sudo systemctl enable /home/ec2-user/my_custom.service
```

I get

```
Failed to enable unit: Access denied
```

And When I run

```
systemctl enable /home/ec2-user/my_custom.service
```

I get

```
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-unit-files ====
Authentication is required to manage system service or unit files.
Authenticating as: Cloud User (ec2-user)
Password: 
==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ====
Failed to enable unit: Access denied
```

Now here I don't have any password to setting the new using `sudo passwd ec2-user` and then using that password but still the same error

Here is content of my_custom.service

```
[Unit]
Description=go_responder
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=ec2-user
ExecStart=/home/ec2-user/custom_service_executable

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem on a Centos 8 Stream box. Turns out it was related to selinux.

You can test this by running `sudo setenforce 0` and then running a `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` again. You should now be able to start/enable your service now (if the problem was selinux).

Example:

```
[root@box ~]# ln -s /path/to/custom.service /etc/systemd/system/
[root@box ~]# systemctl daemon-reload
[root@box ~]# systemctl start oxidized-ng.service
Failed to start custom.service: Unit custom.service not found.

# temporarily setting selinux to permissive
[root@box ~]# setenforce 0
[root@box ~]# systemctl daemon-reload

# systemd can now see the service after a daemon-reload
[root@box ~]# systemctl status custom.service
● custom.service - A service to do all the things...
   Loaded: loaded (/opt/foo/systemd/custom.service; linked; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Answer (score 0):

Systemd units must be placed in one of the [search paths](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#System%20Unit%20Search%20Path) that systemd looks for unit files in. They cannot be placed in any other directory.

Copy the file to `/etc/systemd/system`, run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` and then you will be able to enable your service.

Comment: The same thing works normally and perfectly from /home/user/custom.service in Ubuntu 18 and Centos 7 also. Is this different in RHFL?

Comment: I followed the steps that you said but again the same error on RHEL

Comment: Hm. Does your executable exist? Is it actually executable?

Comment: Yes its an executable. I can run it using the ./executable command. Every time i just get Failed to enable unit: Access denied